# Android fragmentation constructor which take arguments

Tags: android, constructor, fragment

I have the Class MyFragment which extends Fragment.

MyFragment contains different widgets(views) which the user can edit. The initial value of each widget is calculated when the MyFragment fragment is constructed.

And then the user can edit the values afterwards.

The obvious implementation is to have the constructor: MyFragment(String value1,int value2) { } which set the initial widget values and then I just need to implement onSaveInstanceState to persist the value of each widget, so they can be restored by onCreateView.

Easy but there is one problem. I can't add a constructor to MyFragment which take arguments because eclipse/adt will not allow that. Is it safe to just add @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") to the constructor or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use this where foo is a member variable

```
public YourFragment newInstance (Foo foo) {
    YourFragment frag = new YourFragment ();
     frag.setFoo (foo);
     return frag;
}

public void setFoo (Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the solution I use now. But then setFoo must be called, just when the object is constructed, and newer at any other time. So It would give much better code If I could just use a constructor :}

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Fragment.setArguments(Bundle)`. Put the values inside a Bundle and you can read it when `onCreate` or `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated` is invoked.

Comment: But the problem is that the input to setArguments are given to my app each time the fragment is (re)created. I don't want that. The value should only be read when the fragment is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom constructor, build a static method to get a new MyFragment Instance and add a Bundle:

```
public MyFragment newInstance(String value1, int value2) {
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("value1",value1);
    args.putInt("value2",value2);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

In onCreate, retrieve the Bundle and get your values:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String value1 = getArguments().getString("value1");
    int value2 = getArguments().getInt("value2");
}
```

Comment: But that will overwrite any user editions each time the widget is created.